# Angularjs: how to change the date format

Tags: angularjs, date-format

I am getting date in loop from database. The format is like "2015-09-21 18:30:00". But I want to change it as 'dd/MM/yyyy'.
I tried like this

```
{{obj.added_date | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

It shows like

```
2015-09-21 18:30:00 | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

If I use fulldate is shows me like:

```
2015-09-21 18:30:00 | date : 'fullDate'}}
```

for shortDate it shows like this:

```
2015-09-21 18:30:00 | date : 'shortDate'}}
```

Comment: Check whether date : 'dd/mm/yy' is going to work

Comment: make custom filter and use javascript for this.

Comment: @Rajesh: date : 'dd/mm/yy' not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date your passing to view is actually a string and hence angular date filter does not recognise it as date object. You need to convert it to date object first.

Also be careful with firefox, it doesn't work for `new Date();` if date separator in '-' instead '/'. So I would also suggest below

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', function ($scope,$filter) {
       var dateStr = '2015-09-21 18:30:00';
       $scope.dt = $filter('date')(new Date(dateStr.split('-').join('/')), "d/M/yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<bod ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>{{dt}}</div>
</div>
  </body>
```

**EDIT**: I have created a filter which will work for converting string to date object and will work in loop too

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


 myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
   $scope.dt = '2015-09-21 18:30:00'; 
});

myApp.filter('formatDate', function(dateFilter) {
   var formattedDate = '';
   return function(dt) {
     console.log(new Date(dt.split('-').join('/'))); 
     formattedDate = dateFilter(new Date(dt.split('-').join('/')), 'd/M/yyyy');   
     return formattedDate;
   }
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<bod ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>{{dt | formatDate: dt:'d/M/yyyy'}}</div>
</div>
  </body>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it is not single date, it is in loop, not sure how can do like you suggested.

Comment: It that case create your own filter, let me edit my answer for you

Comment: Check out my edited answer, Hope this is what u are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The date format that you have specified doesn't match the input specifications provided in the AngularJS documentation. The following is taken from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

I would suggest that you convert the date value into milliseconds and then pass it into the filter.

Answer (score 0):

What i have done is before bindind the data in angular JS you can format the data

```
//Here i am taking the DOB from session and converted the format in dd-MM-yyyy format
string DOB = ((ABC.Models.Student)Session["Student"]).DOB.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

 //Here i have used a hidden field where i am going to store DOB in ng-Init 
 <input type="hidden" name="DOB" id="DOB" ng_init = "DOB=' " + "Date of Birth: " + DOB + "'"  /><br />
```

Later can call your ng-bind method for displaying.

```
<p ng-bind="DOB"></p>
```

Comment: I am getting date like ""2015-09-21 18:30:00" from DB which is not an object. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Can you post your code, so that i can check the issue